# Issues with ament CmakeLists

Tags: ros, ros2, ament, c++11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I just started out with ROS 2.0. I have the latest build. I am unsure if I am doing something stupid or missing out something. However, I can’t build these simple files. If I should have posted somewhere else kindly let me know.

The command used for building:

`ament build --symlink-install --only-package testpackage`

Error thrown:

```
Process package 'testpackage' with context:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 source_space => /home/artc/ros2_ws/src/ros2/testpackage
  build_space => /home/artc/ros2_ws/build/testpackage
install_space => /home/artc/ros2_ws/install
   make_flags => -j4, -l4
  build_tests => False
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+++ Building 'testpackage'
==> '. /home/artc/ros2_ws/build/testpackage/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make cmake_check_build_system' in '/home/artc/ros2_ws/build/testpackage'
==> '. /home/artc/ros2_ws/build/testpackage/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make -j4 -l4' in '/home/artc/ros2_ws/build/testpackage'
[ 50%] Built target test_lib
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable test_node
CMakeFiles/test_node.dir/src/test_node.cpp.o: In function `main':
test_node.cpp:(.text+0x161): undefined reference to `testRos2::testRos2()'
test_node.cpp:(.text+0x174): undefined reference to `testRos2::initialize(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::node::Node>&)'
test_node.cpp:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `testRos2::~testRos2()'
test_node.cpp:(.text+0x1ef): undefined reference to `testRos2::~testRos2()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/test_node.dir/build.make:123: recipe for target 'test_node' failed
make[2]: *** [test_node] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:136: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/test_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

<== Command '. /home/artc/ros2_ws/build/testpackage/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make -j4 -l4' failed in '/home/artc/ros2_ws/build/testpackage' with exit code '2'
<== Command '. /home/artc/ros2_ws/build/testpackage/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make -j4 -l4' failed in '/home/artc/ros2_ws/build/testpackage' with exit code '2'
```

This is my test_node.cpp

```
#include <testpackage/testpackage.h>
 int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
 rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
 auto node = rclcpp::node::Node::make_shared("test");
 testRos2 test_object;
 test_object.initialize(node);
 rclcpp::spin(node);
 return 0;
}
```

This is my test.cpp

```
#include <testpackage/testpackage.h>
 testRos2::testRos2(){    }
 testRos2::~testRos2(){  }
 void testRos2::initialize(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::node::Node>& n){
}
```

This is my header:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef TESTPACKAGE
#define TESTPACKAGE

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"

using namespace std;

class testRos2{

public:
 testRos2();
~testRos2();
 void initialize(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::node::Node>&);
 };
#endif
```

CMakeLists:

```
project(testpackage)

if(NOT WIN32)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra")
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)

include_directories(include 
            ${rclcpp_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            ${rmw_implementation_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            ${std_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(test_lib
  src/test.cpp
 )
target_link_libraries(test_lib ${rclcpp_LIBRARIES} ${rmw_implementation_LIBRARIES} ${std_msgs})

add_executable(test_node src/test_node.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(test_node test_lib rclcpp std_msgs)

install(
 DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
 DESTINATION include
)

 install(
  TARGETS test_lib test_node 
 ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
 LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
 RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)

ament_package()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270676/issues-with-ament-cmakelists/) by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2017-09-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-09-11**:
Please do not post pictures of text. Please post the text. Also, please do not cross post questions. We see both sites in our notifications already. http://wiki.ros.org/Support

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-09-11**:
Also, it's fine (for ROS 2.0) to post questions here, or on discourse.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-09-11**:
I don't see the error in your cmake, but it is a link error. I would suggest starting with our examples and going from there: https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/master/rclcpp/minimal_publisher Also, you're using `#pragma once` and an include guard, which is redundant.

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2017-09-11**:
@William I have made the changes, apologies for posting the picture and cross posting.

**Comment by [RachelRen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35425/rachelren/) on 2018-05-24**:
@arunavanag
Hi,arunavanag,
I have a question to consult.How to achieve launch service or topic in ROS2 TEST?
I'm writing TEST for the ROS2's project.I learned to launch service or topic via the .test file in ROS,but there is no .test file in ROS2 TEST.What do I need to do to achieve.
Thanks!

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-05-24**:
@RachelRen your question is not related to this thread. Please create a separate question for it rather then commenting on this already long finished one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are multiple problems from a first look at the CMake snippet:

- Your `target_link_libraries()` line contains `${std_msgs}` but that should be `${std_msgs_LIBRARIES}`.
- You can't pass a target name like `test_lib` to `ament_target_dependencies()`. You need `target_link_libraries(test_node test_lib) for that.
- The install rule for the headers is wrong. Either remove the trailing slash from the `DIRECTORY` argument or change the `DESTINATION` to `include/${PROJECT_NAME}`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2017-09-11**:
Thanks @Dirk Thomas

This is where i got confused. Still learning ament.
You can't pass a target name like test_lib to ament_target_dependencies(). You need `target_link_libraries(test_node test_lib) for that.

**Comment by [Leo Richard](https://answers.ros.org/users/41006/leo-richard/) on 2019-07-22**:
Is this answer still valid? Specifically regarding passing target name to `ament_target_dependencies()`? It seems like that is the way it is done in [examples](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/crystal/rclcpp/minimal_publisher/CMakeLists.txt)

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2019-07-23**:
The first argument is a target, and all arguments after must be names of packages that have been found. `ament_target_dependencies(my_target pkg1 pkg2 ...)`. See the function documentation here: https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/e1ff1c1a0a1e08d43e939cdb943a88be601808bd/ament_cmake_target_dependencies/cmake/ament_target_dependencies.cmake#L16-L29